# Individual Docker images

Tags: docker, ssh

I am running an OPC UA Server in a Docker container. The OPC UA Server is connecting to a Cloud Service via a ID and a secret that is stored in a config-File. Furthermore the OPC UA Server holds SSH certificates for authentication.

I see a problem when releasing the image to a work group, because everyone would have access to my personal login, and to SSH certificates that were supposed to be unique to the Host that is running the image.

What would be the appropriate way to inject the certificates and the config-Files into a image, without building the whole thing again?

Answer (score 0):

You have two main ways to pass configuration information into a container at runtime:

1. Use an environment variable for simple string values.
2. Use a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).  You can use a pure Docker volume, but a bind-mounted volume is often useful for things like key stores.  Bind-mounted volumes share a file or directory from the host's filesystem into a specific location on the container filesystem.

Either way, you may need to inject the value into the right place in your config file.  Sometimes config files can have variables from the environment - if not, then you can make your container entrypoint run a script to update the configuration file, and then exec your true entry point.